# Why does adding a caret or tilde cause my semver version to be invalid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, semantic-versioning

I'm using this package: https://github.com/npm/node-semver to do some simple semver version comparisons in a project I'm working on (I'm using the latest 5.3.0 release). This seems like a very safe library to use. In fact, the docs say:

> The semver parser for node (the one npm uses)

So I'm surprised to be running into any issues. I'm get a `TypeError: Invalid Version` when using any of the comparison functions when using some really basic versions, such as: `^1.2.3`, `~1.2.3`, etc. Things work as expected, as long as I exclude the carets/tildes but this seems like something *really* basic. Am I missing something obvious?

Examples (I'm just running these in a Gulp task):

```
// logs 1.2.3
console.log(semver.valid('1.2.3'));

// logs 'null'
console.log(semver.valid('^1.2.3'));

// logs 'null'
console.log(semver.valid('~1.2.3'));

// logs TypeError: Invalid Version ^1.2.3`
console.log(semver.satisfies('1.3.0', '^1.2.3'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a distinction between a version and a version range; `1.2.3` is the former, `^1.2.3` the latter.

The `^1.2.3` and `~1.2.3` don't refer to any one version; there may be multiple versions that satisfy these ranges.

Comment: Yep. You are correct. I definitely understood the distinction, just not how it would impact the way the functions behaved. Now if I do something like:
`const validRange = semver.validRange('^1.2.4');`
`console.log(semver.satisfies('1.3.0', validRange));`
all works as expected.

Thanks for the help!